# _message_fields_schema Automatic Population

Tags: endpoints-proto-datastore

In the examples given by this great library of using `_message_fields_schema()` the example models only have a few attribute references defined. What would be the best way to fill the tuple with all attributes plus the ID?

The best way to describe this, is if I was doing this in SQL:

```
select t.id, t.* from table t
```

A bit contrived but hopefully you get the idea.

Answer (score 2):

The library does not support doing this, but I (the author) am open to suggestions.

At current, you must explicitly name all the fields. For example, from the [simple get sample](http://endpoints-proto-datastore.appspot.com/examples/simple_get.html):

```
from endpoints_proto_datastore.ndb import EndpointsModel

class MyModel(EndpointsModel):

  _message_fields_schema = ('id', 'attr1', 'attr2', 'created')

  attr1 = ndb.StringProperty()
  attr2 = ndb.StringProperty()
  created = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

Feel free to [file a Feature Request](http://code.google.com/p/endpoints-proto-datastore/issues/list).